# Docker Compose: How to prevent db volume being cleared every time a container is build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have dockerfile and compose file set up that works perfectly fine, that runs multiple service. But my problem is every time I do file changes deploy and re-build the containers to apply new changes; my postgres db volume is being recreated hence re-running migrations loosing existing data.

**Dockerfile**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev 

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        libressl-dev \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev make libjpeg \
    && apk del build-deps

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

RUN apk del \
        libressl-dev \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine as runner

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
RUN chmod 755 $APP_HOME/static
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq ffmpeg
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY scripts/entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x $APP_HOME/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY app $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - .env

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.celery
    command: celery -A xxx worker -B -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    environment:
      - DEBUG=True
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web
    env_file:
      - .env

  celery-beat:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.celery
    command: celery -A xxx worker -B -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - web
      - celery
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**docker-compose.stage.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: xxx_stage_web
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
    environment:
      - DEBUG=True
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    container_name: xxx_stage_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env.db

  redis:
    container_name: xxx_stage_redis

  celery:
    build:
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.celery
    container_name: xxx_stage_celery

  celery-beat:
    build:
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.celery
    container_name: xxx_stage_celery_beat


volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

**My entrypoint script**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e  # Configure shell so that if one command fails, it exits

# python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py wait_for_db
python manage.py migrate
# flake8

gunicorn xxx.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 120 --workers 3
```

Am running the above on an EC2 instance.
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.stage.yml up -d --build`
Losing my data every time I have a changed file

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you're setting dependency of db volume.You're creating db volume using separate compose file and db service using the second compose file. so the second compose file might not find/manage that volume.
Try to make volume externally available like this:
In docker-compose.yaml

```
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    external: true
```

**Note**: *I was trying to just add a comment instead an `Answer` because I'm not so sure but its too long to do so.*

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I tried that too but still migrations were being made and data lost

Comment: @vinchuli you're making changes to your web service and then docker compose?

Comment: Am making changes on my web service

Comment: @vinchuli then you cant just update web service separately. You dont need to run compose file again

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: @vinchuli sorry i did typo. I meant if you’re making changes to web service. Then you CAN update it separately. I dont remember exact command but you can find it from documentation. How to update specific service using docker compose.